# How to align single-digit numbers with multi-digit numbers in multi-line equations?

Tags: alignment, alignat

I want to get the following result.

[image]

My attempt below produces something that is not good as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{alignat*}{3}
S   &=   1      &+   2      &+ \cdots &+  99    &+ 100 \\
S   &= 100    &+  99        &+ \cdots &+   2    &+   1\\
2S  &= 101    &+ 101      &+ \cdots &+ 101  &+ 101
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I modified your title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `array` features. Setting the intercolumn spacing to zero and forcing TeX's automatic spacing around binary relations or operations is simple.

In the second example, which I like better, I also added a rule, which you might like.

The `twocolumn` option is just to get a smaller picture.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

Right alignment
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{ r *{5}{ >{{}}c<{{}} r} }
 S &=&   1 &+&   2 &+& \cdots &+&  99 &+& 100 \\
 S &=& 100 &+&  99 &+& \cdots &+&   2 &+&   1 \\
2S &=& 101 &+& 101 &+& \cdots &+& 101 &+& 101
\end{array}
\]
Center alignment
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{ r *{5}{ >{{}}c<{{}} c} }
 S &=&   1 &+&   2 &+& \cdots &+&  99 &+& 100 \\
 S &=& 100 &+&  99 &+& \cdots &+&   2 &+&   1 \\ \cline{3-11}
2S &=& 101 &+& 101 &+& \cdots &+& 101 &+& 101
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add rows as follows:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{ r *{5}{ >{{}}c<{{}} c} }
 S &=&   1 &+&   2 &+& \cdots &+&  99 &+& 100 \\
 S &=& 100 &+&  99 &+& \cdots &+&   2 &+&   1 \\
2S &=& 101 &+& 101 &+& \cdots &+& 101 &+& 101 \\
2S &=& \multicolumn{9}{l}{101\cdot100} \\[1ex]
 S &=& \multicolumn{9}{l}{\!\dfrac{101\cdot100}{2}}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The only trick, besides `\multicolumn`, is `\!` in the last row to countermand the thin space TeX adds in front of the fraction.

Comment: I am interested in the first option titled "Right alignment". Changing `c` in `r *{5}{ >{{}}c<{{}} r}` to either `r` or `l` does not seem to have any different visual effect. Is it correct?

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer No, because all characters in those columns have the same width. But it's really `c` that you want there.

Comment: If I want to add two more rows: `2S=101\times100`  and `S=\frac{101\times100}{2}`, what is the elegant way to merge the columns?

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer -- That sounds like a separate question. If so, please make it so.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Use `\multicolumn` as shown in the edit.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

This may seem rather "manual" but actually ends up using less markup than forcing the alignment through alignment cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\mathcode`\:="8000
{\catcode`\:\active\gdef:{\phantom{0}}}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
S   &= ::1 + ::2 + \cdots + :99 + 100 \\
S   &= 100 + :99 + \cdots + ::2 + ::1 \\
2S  &= 101 + 101 + \cdots + 101 + 101
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Is this basically what I proposed but using `align` instead of `alignat`?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner no, the point here is that your answer (and all the others) is using `&` between the terms I just use a single `&`  on each line to align the `=`

Comment: Ahhh, now I see it! Thx.

Comment: Better not trying this with `babel-french`. ;-)

Comment: @egreg well yes you need to pick a letter that is not otherwise used

Answer (score 6):

Use  `alignat{5}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{5}
S  &=   &   1 &+ {}&   2 &+ \cdots +{} &  99 &+ {}& 100 \\
S  &= & 100 &+ {}&  99 &+ \cdots +   &   2 &+ {}&   1 \\
2S &={} & 101 &+ {}& 101 &+ \cdots +   & 101 &+ {}& 101
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: I just blindly applied `\phantom` without looking into the meaning of `\begin{alignat*}{5}`. Your answer should "win".

Comment: Why do you have some `{}` placed in the code?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner:  it's to ensure the  correct spacing on the right of the  = sign (same as for the  + signs).

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why not every "cell" has `{}`, e. g. in the first row you have `S  &=  ` but in the second row you have `S  &={} `.

Comment: It was not necessary there, because the 1 is a single digit number, and it's flush right to the + (and more generally, numbers after =, since they're in the second column).

Answer (score 5):

The `autoaligne` package provides such alignments out of the box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage {autoaligne}
\begin{document}
\autoaligne{
    S  =   1 +   2 + \cdots +  99 + 100 \\
    S  = 100 +  99 + \cdots +   2 +   1\\
    2S = 101 + 101 + \cdots + 101 + 101
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Cool, never heard of that package.

Answer (score 4):

"Brute force" using `\phantom{}`.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{alignat*}{3}
S   &=  \phantom{00}1      &+   \phantom{00}2      &+ \cdots &+  \phantom{0}99    &+ 100 \\
S   &=  100    &+  \phantom{0}99        &+ \cdots &+   \phantom{00}2    &+   \phantom{00}1\\
2S  &=  101    &+ 101      &+ \cdots &+ 101  &+ 101
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry. The spaces around `+` are not well balanced.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the array environment to achieve the desired alignment automatically without brute forcing with phantom.

```
  \documentclass[preview]{standalone} 
  \usepackage{amsmath} 
    
  \begin{document} 
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax 
  \[ 
  \begin{array}{rcrcrcccrcr} 
      S   &=&   1    &+&   2      &+& \cdots &+&  99  &+& 100 \\ 
      S   &=& 100    &+&  99      &+& \cdots &+&   2  &+&   1\\ 
     2S  &=& 101    &+& 101      &+& \cdots &+& 101  &+& 101 
  \end{array} 
  \] 
  \end{document}
```

Which results in the following

[image: Result of the above Code.]

Comment: you would need to control the inter-column space to get the normal spacing around = and + (see egreg's array version)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed, I did not think of that. Thanks for pointing that out.